# Creating a user reference field based on a similar field on a referenced node

Tags: 7, views, nodes, users

I have 2 content types (project and issue), you can think of this as an OG style set up, the child nodes reference the parent node via a node reference field called "project" on the issue node type.

The "project" node type has a user reference field called "members".

I'm trying to build a view to create a user reference field on "issue" called "assignee", I would like to limit the users that may be referenced to the users who are in the "members" field of the project node.

So I've created a user view with a reference type and am playing with adding contextual relationships and references, but I am getting no results. I know this is a pretty complex way to use these modules, and typically I would just write a module to achieve this, but I would really like to do this without writing a new module.

Has anyone ever dealt with anything like this?

Comment: What field type is the members field? [Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference)? You say *I'm trying to build a view to create a user reference field* - Building a view will not create any new fields. Can you try and make your question clearer as I don't quite understand what your saving at present...

Comment: The "references" module provides both "user reference" and "node reference" fields. The "members" field is a "user reference" field which is clearly stated. The references module allows you to use a view to define the allowed values for the field, that is the view I'm trying to get right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a view with all users.
2. Create a relationship of type reverse join to project via the members field.
3. Create a relationship of type reverse join to issue via the project field.
4. Add a contextual filter on nid using the second join we created (issue).
5. Set the view type to "references".
6. Done :)

Comment: Perfect, I added the "distinct" setting to the query options to limit the duplicate results, but this is what I was looking for thank you!